# Collation urls not followed for Google Webmaster

Tags: wordpress, url, utf-8, collation

I got lots of not followed page on Google Webmaster. I check them and is because lots of url are like http://www.mysite.net/2013/06/burn-notice-7%C3%9702-sub-espanol-online.html
whe the correct url have to be http://www.mysite.net/2013/06/burn-notice-7x02-sub-espanol-online.html

Im try to post a title wit many "x" on it and the only that weird %C3%97 when I post for example a new serie episode like this title: Burn Notice 7x02 Sub Español Online. When the x is between number appear %C3%97 and that made my posts duplicate.

So I try to fix changed the database collation from latin1_swedish_ci to utf8_general_ci but is still the same happend. I check as well my wp-config.php and is define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

Please, some body know any good solution to fix all this situation? The database is quite big and supouse if I find a solution I need update the old url.

Thank you on advance

Answer (score 0):

The URL you say Google is using:

```
http://www.mysite.net/2013/06/burn-notice-7%C3%9702-sub-espanol-online.html
```

is almost the same as the URL:

```
http://www.mysite.net/2013/06/burn-notice-7x02-sub-espanol-online.html
```

as the percent encoded characters actually repreesent [Unicode Character 'MULTIPLICATION SIGN'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00d7/index.htm) aka it's an '×' not an 'x'. Google is just using the percent encoded version to be safe. That means that your database is probably fine, as it is showing URLs as valid UTF8.

The problem probably lies in how you're interpreting the requested URL and trying to match it to the database. PHP should already be decoding the percent encoded value to '×', so either:

- Something is breaking the string (e.g. calling a non-multibyte safe function like strtolower() instead of mb_strtolower()).
- Your PHP code is connecting to the database in a character set other than UTF8, please check that your my.cnf file contains 'default-character-set=utf8' in the client section.

or there's some other issue. The URL does appear valid though.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for you anwer. I make a sql query and what you said is not there. So I talk with my host to see if then can edit my mysql /etc/my.cnf and that will fix the problem...

Comment: Well... i can confirm that is everything working on the server. And then confirm the problem is a wordpress files not the server. The issue can be something relative with sanitize on formating.php file? Regards

Comment: Can you post the wordpress code or plugin that you're using to convert the URL to a DB request?

Comment: The file is to big to post here but here is a pastebin link in which you can see the file

http://pastebin.com/fdpe1XCQ

Regards